# How do i copy an array from a lua file

Tags: arrays, lua

I Want to copy an array from a text file and make another array equal it
so

```lua
local mapData = {
    grass = {
        cam = "hud",
        x = 171,
        image = "valley/grass",
        y = 168,
        animated = true
    }
}
```

This is an array that is in Data.lua

i want to copy this array and make it equal another array

```lua
local savedMapData = {}
savedMapData = io.open('Data.lua', 'r')
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want to copy (http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) or load a file (https://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=dofile), but one of these should help you.

Comment: Add `return mapData` at the end of Data.lua and do `local savedMapData = dofile('Data.lua')`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Lua Version what you can do further.
But i like questions about file operations.
Because filehandlers in Lua are Objects with methods.
The datatype is userdata.
That means it has methods that can directly be used on itself.
Like the methods for the datatype string.
Therefore its easy going to do lazy things like...

```
-- Example open > reading > loading > converting > defining
-- In one Line - That is possible with methods on datatype
-- Lua 5.4
local savedMapData = load('return {' .. io.open('Data.lua'):read('a'):gsub('^.*%{', ''):gsub('%}.*$', '') .. '}')()

for k, v in pairs(savedMapData) do print(k, '=>', v) end
```

Output should be...

```
cam =>  hud
animated    =>  true
image   =>  valley/grass
y   =>  168
x   =>  171
```

If you need it in the `grass` table then do...

```
local savedMapData = load('return {grass = {' .. io.open('Data.lua'):read('a'):gsub('^.*%{', ''):gsub('%}.*$', '') .. '}}')()
```

The Chain of above methods do...

1. io.open('Data.lua') - Creates Filehandler (userdata) in read only mode
2. (userdata):read('a') - Reading whole File into one (string)
3. (string):gsub('^.*%{', '') - Replace from begining to first { with nothing
4. (string):gsub('%}.*$', '') - Replace from End to first } with nothing

Comment: Not a fan of your string manipulation on Lua sources.